# How to Zoom in/out an UIView based on Pan gesture?

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to Zoom in/out an `UIView` based on the `UIPanGesture`. I don't know how to convert `translationInView` to Scaling parameter. (I know how to zoom in/out based on pinch gesture).

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but no such luck so far.

Comment: You can't do it using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Use `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi, I'm sure you *can* do it with a pan gesture recogniser. It's just an unusual technique. Apple seem to do it with assistive touch using a diagonal pan gesture.

Comment: No pan gesture is use to just move the object, it is not able to perform zoom effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make zoom you need UIPinchGestureRecognizer, not Pan

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;    
}
```

Also check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) link.

UPDATE:

The only way to receive touches information from UIPanGestureRecognizer is

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfTouches;
- (CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView*)view;
```

so maybe you can try something like this:

```
    CGFloat old_distance = 0.0; // keep it somewhere between touches!

- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2) {
        CGPoint a = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:recognizer.view];
        CGPoint b = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:recognizer.view];
        CGFloat xDist = (a.x - b.x);
        CGFloat yDist = (a.y - b.y);
        CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));

        CGFloat scale = 1;
        if (old_distance != 0) {
            scale = distance / old_distance;
        }
        old_distance = distance;
        recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew how to achieve it through pinch gesture. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. But I still do not think using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is a good idea.